# How to pass huge data from html to jsp

Tags: html, string, forms, jsp

I'm passing data from a text area from html form to jsp. It's working for small data, however breaks if I pass a data of around 1MB and above. I'm storing the data in a String variable in JSP. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use form method='post' like below :

```
<form action="" method="post"> </form>
```